# Editing lines and legend on ggplot barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following bar plot:

[image]

I would like to change the plot in the following ways:

- I would like the green line on the plot to be a dashed line rather than a solid line
- I would like the legend to show the green line as a dashed green line in the box for "high_pass".

While this should be easy, it has proven quite difficult for me to solve. Does anyone know how I can fix my code below to achieve the goals outlined above?

```
threshold <- data.frame(x = c(2, 2.7), group = c("pass", "high_pass"),
  color = c("red", "darkgreen"), line=c("dashed", "solid"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
group.colors <- c("Overall" ="#FFD580", "ELA" = "#CBC3E3", "Math" = "lightyellow", "Essential Skills"="lightpink")

#Distributions of Capstone Scores
ggplot(df, aes(x = score, y = ..density.., fill = area)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 12, color = "black") + 
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  facet_grid(area~cohort)   +
  scale_fill_manual(values=group.colors)+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = x,  colour=group), threshold, show.guide = TRUE) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "statistics", values = c(pass = "red", high_pass="darkgreen"))+
  labs(x = "Overall Score", y = "Density", title = "Barplots of Average Score Distributions by Year and Domain")
```

My main data frame for this plot (df) is structured in the following way:

| cohort | area | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20-21 | Overall | 2.5 |
| 20-21 | ELA | 2.2 |
| 20-21 | Math | 2.6 |
| 20-21 | Essential Skills | 2.8 |
| 21-22 | Overall | 2.9 |
| 21-22 | ELA | 3.0 |
| 21-22 | Math | 3.0 |
| 21-22 | Essential Skills | 2.8 |
| 22-23 | Overall | 2.0 |
| 22-23 | ELA | 2.5 |
| 22-23 | Math | 1.8 |
| 22-23 | Essential Skills | 2.0 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map `group` on the `linetype` aes too, then set your desired linetypes using `scale_linetype_manual`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = score, y = ..density.., fill = area)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 12, color = "black") +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  facet_grid(area ~ cohort) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = group.colors) +
  geom_vline(
    aes(xintercept = x, colour = group, linetype = group),
    threshold,
    show.guide = TRUE
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    name = "statistics",
    values = c(pass = "solid", high_pass = "dashed")
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = "statistics",
    values = c(pass = "red", high_pass = "darkgreen")
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "Overall Score", y = "Density",
    title = "Barplots of Average Score Distributions by Year and Domain"
  )
```

[image]